# Error on listing the elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`4[System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.DateTime]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ControllerName]'.

I did the code migration (database update) after that I want to just list the items by column name My code is as follows

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  DB db = new DB();
  var categorylist = from a in db.categories
                     select new
                     {
                       a.CategoryName, 
                       a.ID, 
                       a.stock, 
                       a.EntryDate
                     };
  return View(categorylist.ToList());
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance.

View is as follows

```
@model IEnumerable<Categories.Models.Categories>
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") </p> <table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.stock)</th>
    <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EntryDate)</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  @foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.stock)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EntryDate)</td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
  </tr> 
}
</table>
```

Comment: Please read the help files to learn how to format your code blocks. Not you html is invalid - your have an opening `<p>` tag and a closing `</table>` tag

Comment: The error is caused by `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryName)`. Your model is a collection, not an object (`IEnumerable` does not contain a property `CategoryName`). Refer my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take advantage of the model binding features of MVC you should create a view model which represents those the properties you want to display and/or edit (adjust property types as required)

```
public class CategoryVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; } 
  public string CategoryName { get; set; }
  public int Stock { get; set; }
  public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
}
```

and change you method to

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  DB db = new DB();
  var categorylist = (from a in db.categories
                 select new CategoryVM
                 {
                   CategoryName = a.CategoryName, 
                   ID = a.ID, 
                   Stock = a.stock, 
                   EntryDate = a.EntryDate
                 }).ToList();
  return View(categorylist);
}
```

View

```
@model List<CategoryVM>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category Name</th>
      <th>stock</th>
      <th>Entry Date</th>
      ...
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ID)<td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CategoryName)</td>
        ...
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to Change the model type thar you defined in your view

Edit: Try

```
@model IList<dynamic>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply..... I changed the type from to IEnumerable to Ilist but still getting error :(

Comment: Can you please post your view as well?

Comment: Try '@model IList<dynamic>'

Comment: Got this error
'System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryName' and no extension method 'CategoryName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Ok, as I said earlier, please post your view code :-)

Comment: Bro, the view is simple which MVC creates to list using scafollding
@model IEnumerable<Categories.Models.Categories>

Code is working for 
"return View(db.categories.ToList());" But its not working if I take the way which stephen mentioned.

Comment: @Sketcher, Whats not working? You are doing something wrong in your view (particularly if your error is `System.Collections.Generic.IList<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryName`) so post your view.

Comment: Can you explain why you have used `@model IList<...>` and not `@model List<...>`? I am learning all this as well. IMO `IList<>` is an interface that you inherits from with implemented methods. Also, `IList<>` cannot be instantiated because this is an interface. I did not confirm those, though.